# Spark : Sending resource file path to spark executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I need to pass the location of a resource file path from driver to executors. 
To achieve this , i am trying to set executor enviornmnet variable. 
The code looks as follws:

```
class AppMain{
 def main(args : Array[String]){
    val resourcePath = "/a/"
    sparkConf.setExecutorEnv("RESOURCEPATH", resourcePath)
}
class B{
 println(System.getenv("RESOURCEPATH")) // This returns null
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this or what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In spark you can directly use any variable within a closure of called action.

```
String my_path="path";
rdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> immutableBytesWritableResultTuple2) throws Exception {
            return my_path;
       }
   });
```

Suggestion: if you are testing locally then, check if executor process is created or if the executor is runned inside the same JVM as driver. Because environment variables are set only when executor is launching.

Comment: Thanks .. But my application has many classes and objects. While instantiating a object , i needed enviornment variable. 
I am not sure how that can be achieved with this approach. I am testing in cluster and I can see the env value as null in executor logs